# Getting from Macau (Taipa) to Hong Kong (Tin Wan)

Tags: transit, china, hong-kong, macau

How do I get from Macau (for example, Inn Hotel Macau) to Hong Kong (specifically, Mojo Nomad Aberdeen Harbour)?

I've been thinking about taking a bus through the new bridge. I assume it departs from HZMB Macau Port. How to get there? And I suppose I'll have to change buses in HK to get to my destination. What's the best option?

If taking a ferry is a better option, I will consider it too.

Comment: How about taking a ferry to China Ferry Terminal and then taking bus 973 from the "China Hong Kong City" bus stop to the "Tin Wan Street; Shek Pai Wan Road" bus stop? That's what Rome2Rio suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question given the specific, unconventional (and somehow unfortunate) choice of hotels.

Nowadays, Macau hotels usually provide complimentary shuttle bus service to customers. [Inn Hotel seems to be no exception](https://macau.innhotel.com/index.php/en/), but after a closer look... (emphasis mine)

> To welcome guests from the first moment they arrive, we provide a complementary shuttle bus service to and from the **Grand Emperor Hotel** and Macau Ferry Terminal & Rorta Do Cerco.

What's the hotel name again? I think you'd better ask the hotel about the exact details of the shuttle bus.

From Macau to Hong Kong there are three Macau ports, sorted from nearest to farthest from hotel: Taipa Ferry Terminal, Outer Harbour Ferry Terminal, and Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge Macau Port. Please ask if the hotel provide shuttle bus to which of these ports. When you have luggage, using hotel shuttle bus is always better than taking public transport in Macau. If the hotel *really* fails you, take [TransMac 26](https://www.transmac.com.mo/routes-services/routes/?routefrom&routeto&route=26)  from Jardim Cidade das Flores to Taipa Ferry, or [TCM 28A](http://www.tcm.com.mo/web/showroute.asp?rt=28A) from Treasure Garden to Outer Harbour, or [Transmac 102X](http://www.dsat.gov.mo/bus/site/route_display.aspx?route=busroute_102X) from Treasure Garden to HZMB Macau port.

If you take the ferry from Taipa or Outer Harbour, always pick Macau Ferry Pier (in Sheung Wan, Hong Kong Island) as your destination, instead of China Ferry Terminal (in Tsim Sha Tsui, Kowloon). It is because (1) there are more ferries going to Macau Ferry than to China Ferry, and (2) Macau Ferry is closer to your destination. After the ferry trip, take [CityBus 37B](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-37B-37B-D.pdf) (Macau Ferry -> Tin Wan St) or [CityBus 71](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-71-71-D.pdf) (Macau Ferry -> Hing Wo St).

If you use HZMB, you will, in HZMB Macau port, buy a ticket for a bus ride ("Golden Bus") to HZMB Hong Kong port. There, you need to take two buses: [Citybus A11](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A11-A11-D.pdf)/[A21](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A21-A21-D.pdf)/[A22](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A22-A22-D.pdf)/[A29](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A29-A29-D.pdf) to Lantau Link Toll Plaza, then [CityBus A10](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A10-A10-D.pdf) to alight at Tin Wan St. To enjoy a much cheaper bus fare, pay by Octopus card for interchange discount.

So you have three main options, each with minor variants:

1. Take hotel shuttle or TransMac 26 to Taipa Ferry; take Cotai Jet ferry to Macau Ferry; take CityBus 37B/71 to your destination.
2. Take hotel shuttle or TCM 28A to Outer Harbour Ferry; take TurboJet ferry to Macau Ferry; take CityBus 37B/71 to your destination.
3. Take hotel shuttle or Transmac 102X to HZMB Macau port; take "Golden Bus" to HZMB Hong Kong port; take Citybus A11/A21/A22/A29 to Lantau Link Toll Plaza; take Citybus A10 to your destination.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It's interesting that in spite of the fact that China Ferry Terminal is farther away from my destination than Macau Ferry Pier, Google Maps says that taking bus 973 from the former will take only 2 minutes more than taking bus 71 from Macau Ferry. Originally I wanted to try a bus through the new bridge (since I already used ferries last year), but it seems that taking a ferry would involve less hassle, given my destination.

Comment: By the way, is there space for a full-size carry on luggage on buses 37B, 71? If not (or even if there is), can I take the luggage on the second floor of the bus with me and store it on a seat beside me?

Comment: @user77409 Neither 37B nor 71 provide luggage rack, as they are urban bus routes instead of border-connecting bus routes. A11/A21/A22/A29/A10 belong to the latter and has luggage rack. On a bus without luggage rack, I recommend finding a space in the lower deck to put your luggage and sit next to it.